# IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, ssl, websphere

For application client running in WAS 8.5 we have code creating socket that fails with an error below.

```
    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket();
    String pickedCipher[] = {"TLS_DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"};
    socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(pickedCipher);
    String[] protocols = socket.getEnabledProtocols();
```

log:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite
>   SSL_DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256     at com.ibm.jsse2.r.a(r.java:245)    at
>   com.ibm.jsse2.s.(s.java:51)     at
>   com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:186)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of supported ciphersuite in Java - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Comment: spelling mistake and all there is
Thanks!